# Display music videos per artist and artists per music video

Tags: sql, join

**dbFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/i3FtETqg**

I've joined three tables but I need more specific results.

Table 1: videos - names of videos
Table 2: artists - names of artists
Table 3: roles - connects videos with artists appearing in them

The results have duplicates in both columns:
Artist Name duplicates when an artist has multiple music videos
Video Title duplicates when multiple artists appear in a music video

---

```
CREATE TABLE videos (id INT UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TABLE artists (id INT UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TABLE roles (id INT UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, video_id INT, artist_id INT);
```

---

```
INSERT INTO videos (title) VALUES ('One vs Many'), ('Nikola Tesla'), ('Seat @ the Table'), ('Vinyl');
INSERT INTO artists (name) VALUES ('Mental Stamina'), ('Mozay Calloway'), ('Melatto');
INSERT INTO roles (video_id,artist_id) VALUES (1,1), (2,1), (3,2), (3,3), (4,2);
```

---

```
SELECT artists.name, videos.title FROM roles INNER JOIN artists on artists.id = roles.artist_id INNER JOIN videos on videos.id = roles.video_id GROUP BY roles.artist_id, roles.video_id ORDER BY roles.artist_id;
```

---

**Current Output**
name - title

- Mental Stamina - One vs Many
- Mental Stamina - Nikola Tesla
- Mozay Calloway - Seat @ the Table
- Mozay Calloway - Vinyl
- Melatto - Seat @ the Table

---

**Desired Output 1: Artists with Videos**

- Mental Stamina - One vs Many, Nikola Tesla
- Mozay Calloway - Seat @ the Table, Vinyl
- Melatto - Seat @ the Table

---

**Desired Output 2: Videos with Artists**

- One vs Many - Mental Stamina
- Nikola Tesla - Mental Stamina
- Seat @ the Table - Mozay Calloway, Melatto
- Vinyl - Mozay Calloway**

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have different functions for this.)

Comment: If you're using MySQL, check out `group_concat()`.

Comment: cool, I didn't know `group_concat()`. Seems to be fun https://dbfiddle.uk/LnMUOKtQ :-)

Comment: This is exactly the syntax I was looking for but didn't know existed. I was debugging using group by to assemble the data but all the examples I saw used SUM to total up a set of integers when I needed to CONCAT data. So I tried to CONCAT after the GROUP BY but it was messy. This was instead poetic, thank you!